# How to ack-grep replace a string of multiple words

Tags: bash, grep, ack

The following command replaces every occurence of the word `from` in any file of the current directory or its subdirectories with `to`:

```
ack-grep -l --print0 --text from | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e 's/from/to/g'
```

I got that from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529345/best-way-to-do-a-find-replace-in-several-files) thread.

How do I replace a string including multiple words instead of one word? E.g. replace `laughing babies` by `smiling little children`.

I tried the following but these did not work:

```
ack-grep -l --print0 --text 'laughing babies' | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e "s/'laughing babies'/'smiling little children'/g"
ack-grep -l --print0 --text 'laughing babies' | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e 's/"laughing babies"/"smiling little children"/g'
```

Don't know if it matters but I'm on `Ubuntu 11.10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need the quotes, `sed` can deal with spaces and the quotes are taken as being part of the pattern (unless you escape them). Just do this:

```
ack-grep -l --print0 --text 'laughing babies' | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e 's/laughing babies/smiling little children/g'
```

I don't see why you want the `grep` part though, you could just run `sed` directly on all files of the directory, `sed` is fast:

```
sed -i -e 's/laughing babies/smiling little children/g' *
```

Comment: Because ack-grep omits certain files like those in .git in its search. But that sed command is good to know nevertheless, thanks!